What's the name of the manga about the student who wakes up as a lake?
I can't remember the name of the manga, but I know it's about a student boy who falls asleep in class and wakes up as a lake in another world. He then starts gaining the ability to control water. What's the name of this manga?

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Regular lake, or hot springs?

Isekai de Mizu no Dai Seirei Yattemasu. Ko ni Teni Shita Ore no Hatarakanai Henkyou Kaitaku


When Nagi Saejima, a carefree high school student, wakes up from a doze, he became a lake in a different world!? Nagi, w finds out that he is the "Great Spirit of Water" whose main body is the lake, heals those who suffer from injuries and diseases with the power that dwells in himself. One day, Nagi is led by a voice calling for help and summoned by a boy. That encounter will greatly change the fate of Nagi.

Found with a search for manga isekai "a lake"
